# Javascript jQuery style.backgroundSize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the following code to adjust the backgroundSize of an element called remote:

```
document.getElementById('remote').style.backgroundSize = '80% 100%';
```

However, i'm trying to get it to work using the method below:

```
$("#remote").style.backgroundSize = '80% 100%';
```

The first method works but the second method is not working.

Any suggestions what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it via jquery, try the following.

```
$("#remote").css("background-size", "80% 100%");
```

Answer (score 1):

What you do wrong is that [`$('#remote')`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) does not return a DOM element like `document.getElementById('remote')` does, but a [jQuery Object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) instead which is a collection containing the DOM elements matching the selector.

Since the `[]` operator works on this collection just like on a simple array, you can call `$('#remote')[0]` to get first DOM element in this collection. Since the `id` is a unique identifier in the DOM, so you can be sure that the first element would be the one you want.

You can also call [`$('#remote').get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) which [essentially does the same](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/).

So you can either call `$('#remote').get(0).style.backgroundSize = '80% 100%'` or `$('#remote')[0].style.backgroundSize = '80% 100%'`, they will yield the same result.

jQuery also offers a function to modify the css properties of all elements matched by a selector with [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/). This - apart from offering a slightly shorter syntax - is fairly useful in cases where there are more than one matched element (like `$('li').css('backgroundColor', 'black')` changes the background color of every `<li>` element). In your case you can use this function like `$('#remote').css('backgroundSize', '80% 100%')`. This is slightly (unnoticably) slower. Also it doesn't result in an exception thrown in case of no matching elements, while the other three (including the original one in the question) methods do.

So in summary you can achieve this with either of the following lines:

```
$('#remote')[0].style.backgroundSize = '80% 100%'
$('#remote').get(0).style.backgroundSize = '80% 100%'
$('#remote').css('backgroundSize', '80% 100%')
```

And as a footnote I wouldn't change `document.getElementById('remote').style.backgroundSize = '80% 100%'` if it's already working for you. It only worths "jQueryfying" your code if it offers simpler code structure not just a little shorter syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
$("#remote").css("background-size":"80% 100%");
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this threw a syntax error as the `:` operator makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#remote").get(0).style.backgroundSize = '80% 100%';

$("#remote") // return jquery object
$("#remote").get(0) // return dom object
```